# What regex expression can replace every other word?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Given the following sentence: `Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.`, what regex expression would allow me to filter out every other word? I am doing my replace like this:

```
"Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.".replace(/regex goes here/gi, "replace string goes here")
```

So I want to create a regex expression that will turn that sentence into either `Fredrick many exquisite jewels.` or `crazy bought very opal`.

Comment: If you found the answer would you mind sharing? Additionally would it be possible to implement this into Sublime text 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use the following (assumes your words are all matched by \w)

```
"Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.".replace(/(\w+) (\w+)/g, '$1');
-> "Crazy bought very opal."
```

Replacing $1 with $2 gives you:

```
"Fredrick many exquisite jewels."
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if RegEx is the right tool, but you could `split` the string by space into an array and then use `filter` to remove the odd or even elements:

```
var s = "Crazy Fredrick brought many very exquisite opal jewels";

s.split(/\s+/)
    .filter(function (_, index) { 
        return index % 2 !== 0; // only want "odd" words
    }).join(" ");

// yields "Fredrick many exquisite jewels"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you can try using these regexes:

```
\b\S+\b\s?(?=((\b\S+\b\s?){2})*\.?$)
\b\S+\b\s?(?=\b\S+\b\s?((\b\S+\b\s?){2})*\.?$)
```

Explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/kR3hS5